# Identify the population and the sample

Tags: sampling, descriptive-statistics, sample

> Identify the population and the sample.
>
> (i). A survey of $1353$ households in a city found that $18\%$ of households own a computer.
>
> (ii). A recent survey of $2625$ primary school children found that $28\%$ of the children in a district could be classified obese
>
> (iii). The average weight of every sixth person entering the mall within $3$ hour period was $68kg$.

- population - All households in a city , Sample - $1353$ households in this city
- population  - All primary school children , Sample - $2625$ primary school children
- population - All persons entering the mall within $3$ hour period , Sample - Six person entering the mall within $3$ hour period

Here is my answer but last one is bit complicated to me help me to identify?

Comment: (iii) is strangely written.  Was it "every six***th*** person entering the mall"?

Comment: @Henry Yes thank you. I edited it. How did you know it was typo?

Comment: If it is every sixth person then the sample is not six but a sixth of the people

Comment: @Henry Got it thank you very much

Comment: Sometimes it is useful to distinguish between the 'target' population of major interest and the accessible 'sampled' population. In (iii) the target population may be people who go to malls (or a particular mall, or a particular mall in the afternoon), and the sampled population is people who go to that mall during the 3-hr time period (one hopes in the afternoon) when a survey worker is available.